# Teams: Can I have access to my Files (Sharepoint) using resource-specific consent permissions?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, sharepoint-online

We have a published app in the Teams App Store.

We want to let the bot to have access to Teams Files. This is possible using Graph Application Permissions.
But there's a small problem, the "**Files.Read.All**" and "**Files.ReadWrite.All**" seems like overkill to our clients and they are not going to let us access all SharePoint resources just to upload a file into Teams Directory.

Resource-specific consent looks like a solution for our purposes.
However, after checking the documentation and samples we've found out that there are no "**Files.ReadWrite.Group**" and "**Sites.ReadWrite.Group**" resource-specific consent permissions.
Despite that, we tried to add them but got an error during the app installation process.

When we're requesting the channel information from graph api using resource-specific consent permissions we get:

```
{
    ...
    "filesFolderWebUrl": "https://example.sharepoint.com/sites/RSC/Shared Documents/General",
    ...
}
```

If we try to request `GET {filesFolderWebUrl}` with auth token we get 401 UNAUTHORIZED.
We also tried to use `https://example.sharepoint.com/_api/` and it fails with:

```
{
    "error_description":"Exception of type 'Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.AudienceUriValidationFailedException' was thrown."
}
```

The `GET https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/sites/` request returns blank response:

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/$metadata#sites",
    "value": []
}
```

Is there a way to get access to Teams Files using resource-specific consent? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please have a look at this doc-
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-list-children?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#examples
Let us know if you have any query.

Comment: @Sayali-MSFT Thanks for the response.
GET /me/drive/root/children unable to use cause this is for delegated.
GET /drives/ - got "code": "accessDenied" response.

Comment: For Accessing the GET API /drives/  .The signed in user's drive (when using delegated authentication) can be accessed from the me singleton.
   If a user's OneDrive is not provisioned but the user has a license to use OneDrive, this request will automatically provision the user's drive, when using delegated authentication

Comment: @Sayali-MSFT, the OP is asking about Teams / SharePoint Online access, while you refer to `/me`  OneDrive for Business access, which I think is irrelevant to this Q.

Comment: @Oleksa how did you create the client credentials that you connect with then from code to SP/Graph API?

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative to RSC you could use SharePoint Site collection Level Permission
aka **"*The SharePoint flavour of RSC*"**
using the ``Sites.Selected` Graph permission.

This will allow a Customer Admin to grant your app/bot access to specific SharePoint SiteCollections.

While this does not give the 'automagical' permissions when a Teams App is installed in a team, it will allow you to use App Permissions with a scope that is both controllable, and smaller than 'entire tenant'

[image: Allow the application to access a subset of site collections without a signed in user. The specific site collections and the permissions granted will be configured in SharePoint Online.]

See:

- PG Blog Bost & Demo:
  https://devblogs.microsoft.com/microsoft365dev/controlling-app-access-on-specific-sharepoint-site-collections/
- Blogpost with samples : https://dev.to/svarukala/use-microsoft-graph-to-set-granular-permissions-to-sharepoint-online-sites-for-azure-ad-application-4l12
- Create **Site Permission**: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/site-post-permissions?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

Comment: @Oleksa - Could you please confirm if your issue has resolved with above suggestion or still looking for any help?

Comment: @jos-verlinde Thanks. This looks like what we need.

Comment: @Sayali-MSFT Yes. We need some time to implement this and test. But i guess this is exactly what we need.

Answer (score 1):

Team (group) resource-specific consent doesn't currently support access to the team's files.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Do you know, maybe there's some workaround. We need to let bot access only one dir or teams attachments drive only. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

There are some new graph scopes (preview) you could try:

- `Files.Read.Selected` - allows read access to files user can select.
- `Files.ReadWrite.Selected` - allows read/write access to files user can select
- **`Files.ReadWrite.AppFolder`** - allows access to files in the "app folder". This one looks promising in your case.

These are new, and in "preview" state at the moment of writing, but already available for the apps. Disclaimer: I have not tried them myself yet, just discovered recently.